# How to share scope between functions in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm not sure if this is a d3.js question or a javascript visibility question. I have two functions that assign the same event listener to different nodes:

```
function render_line(){
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal();
    ...

    d3.select("#my_line").on("click", onclick);
}

function render_bar(){
    var y= d3.scale.linear();
    ...

    d3.select("#my_bar").on("click", onclick);
}

function onclick(d,i){
    use(x,y) // error: can't access x or y
    ...
}
```

I think it makes sense for both `render_line()` and `render_bar()` to share the same event listener function because clicking on one should also update the other but I don't know how the solve the variable scope issue.

Comment: Does the `onclick` handler really need to have access to both x and y, or do you just want access to one or the other?

Comment: Both, besides x and y there are other variables, like the placeholders for the 2 svg tags (one for lines and the other for bars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the variables outside your functions and then assign to them (without using the `var` keyword in the function) then your functions will be *[closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)*, granted access to set and get values from those variables.

```
var x,y;
function foo(){
  x = d3.scale.ordinal();
  d3.select("...").on("click",onclick);
}
function bar(){
  y = d3.scale.linear();
  d3.select("...").on("click",onclick);
}
function onclick(){
  // has access to both x and y here
}
```

Alternatively, if that's too dirty feeling, then create a closure around the local variable during event registration, passing the value to your shared function:

```
function foo(){
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal();
  d3.select("...").on("click",function(evt){
    onclick.call(this,evt,x);
  });
}
function foo(){
  var y = d3.scale.linear();
  d3.select("...").on("click",function(evt){
    onclick.call(this,evt,y);
  });
}
function onclick(evt,scale){
  // Use 'scale' passed in
}
```

Note that in this case you cannot unregister `onclick` later because that was not the function that was registered with the handler.

Comment: I like it. I didn't know about apply(). Thanks